# Make a row in UITableView point to a URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a table which lists out items I would to make each of the row in the table to point to a URL which is assigned to each item.

Comment: Yep every entry in a row points to a different URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tableview delegate function didSelectRowAtIndexPath you can use this code to open a url in the Safari application.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"]; 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When a cell is selected, the `-tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method will be called. From there, assuming you have the url for each row, the following code will open the URL `url` in Safari.

```
NSURL *url = /* Assume this exists */;
if( [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url] )
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to leave your app, you can open the url in a UIWebView.

```
    UIWebView * wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
    [self.view addSubview:wv];  // or push onto Navigation Stack
    // if adding wv as subview, also need to add a back button to self.view to dismiss webview.

    [wv loadRequest:
          [NSURLRequest  requestWithURL:
                 [NSURL   URLWithString:  myURLForSelectedRow]]];
    [wv autorelease];
```